# How exactly does the ?: operator work in C?

Tags: c, syntax, increment, conditional-operator, post-increment

I have a question, how the compiler operate on the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int b=12, c=11;
  int d = (b == c++) ? (c+1) : (c-1);
  printf("d = %i\n", d);
}
```

I am not sure why the result is ‍‍‍`d = 11`.

Comment: Why are you not sure? What else would you expect and why?

Comment: I don't recall the precise semantics involved, but you may be observing undefined behavior.

Comment: No, @chepner, there is a sequence point after evaluating the condition of a ternary, before evaluating the selected alternative.  That avoids the UB vector I suppose you're thinking of.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure where I thought the compiler would have a choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Translated to a regular if-statement your code would look like this:

```
int b=12, c=11;
int d;

if (b == c++)
   d = c+1;
else
   d = c-1;
```

The clue here is that c is incremented **after** the condition is checked. So you enter the `else` state but c already has the value 12 there.

Answer (score 6):

In `int d = (b == c++) ? (c+1) : (c-1);`:

- The value of `c++` is the current value of `c`, 11. Separately, `c` is incremented to 12.
- `b == 11` is false, since `b` is 12.
- Since `(b == c++)` is false, `(c-1)` is used. Also, the increment of `c` to 12 must be completed by this point.
- Since `c` is 12, `c-1` is 11.
- `d` is initialized to that value, 11.

Answer (score 5):

According to the C Standard (6.5.15 Conditional operator)

> 4 The first operand is evaluated; there is a sequence point between
>   its evaluation and the evaluation of the second or third operand
>   (whichever is evaluated). The second operand is evaluated only if the
>   first compares unequal to 0; the third operand is evaluated only if
>   the first compares equal to 0; the result is the value of the second
>   or third operand (whichever is evaluated), converted to the type
>   described below.110)

So in the initializing expression of this declaration

```
int d = (b == c++) ? (c+1) : (c-1);
```

the variable `b` is compared with the value of the variable `c` because the post-increment operator returns the value of its operand before incrementing it.

As the values are not equal each other (`b` is set to 12 while `c` is set to 11) then the sub-expression `(c-1)` is evaluated.

According to the quote there is a sequence point after evaluation of the condition of the operator. It means that after evaluation of the condition `c` has the value `12` after applying the post-increment operator to the variable `c`. As a result the variable d is initialized by the value `1` (`12 - 1`).

Comment: The only correct answer - this specific case must be answered by mentioning the sequence point in `?:`. Because normally in C, combining `++` with other operations on the same operand is undefined behavior. And this code only works predictably because the `?:` has various special snowflake rules.

Answer (score 4):

Beacuse the condition is false, therefore the `false` case will happen: `c-1`, but since you incremented `c` in the condition by `c++`, therefore `c` is now `12`. The result thus 12 - 1 which is 11.

EDIT:
What OP misunderstood was the post increment.

So what actually happen is like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  int b=12, c=11;
  int d;

  if (b == c) { // 12 == 11 ? -> false
    c = c + 1;
    d = c + 1;
  } else { // this executes since condition is false
    c = c + 1; // post increment -> c++ -> c = 12 now
    d = c - 1; // 12 - 1 = 11 -> d = 11
  }
  printf("d = %i\n", d);
}
```

Comment: I think the OP is referring to the order of operations, given the `c++` in the condition. The condition is false, but then the *orginal* value of `c` is used to compute `c - 1`, not the incremented version.

Comment: But thats not true since the new c value is used or am I missing the point of yours?

Comment: I think there might be a misunderstanding between `c++` and `++c`

Comment: @N00b `c++` is the *post*-increment operator. The value of `c++` is 11, with the side effect of making `c == 12`. `++c` would have the value of 12.

Comment: Actually what will happen is 12 == 11 condition check, then c is incremented.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [Ternary Operator.](https://guide.freecodecamp.org/c/ternary-operator/)

**Syntax**

> condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false

So, you wrote

```
int d = (b == c++) ? (c+1) : (c-1);
```

In this situation, the result will be 11 because, after if checks, 'c' value is increased(c+1=12) and only after that it sets 'd' value as c(12)-1 which is 11.

If you used, for example:

```
int d = (b == ++c) ? (c+1) : (c-1);
```

"c" value would be increased before checking the statement, so it would be true and "d" value would be c(12)+1 which is 13.